# Are PIN lock and lock screen widgets incompatible in ICS?

Tags: 4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, samsung-galaxy-nexus, lock-screens, motorola-droid-bionic

My wife has a Bionic and I've got a Galaxy Nexus. So she has the older Android version and I've got ICS. We both use PIN locks.

On her phone, she first has to swipe-unlock to get to the PIN screen, which means her first screen has lock widgets on it.

On my phone, I only see the PIN screen. This means I don't have any lock widgets, which is disappointing. I have to unlock my phone in order to mess with music that is playing.

My question is: is this an ICS issue or is there a setting I missed that lets me see the lock screen (with widgets) before the PIN screen?

Answer (score 1):

Seems to work for me -- here's what I see:

[image: Screenshot]
<sup>(Click image to enlarge)</sup>

Comment: That's great for the Music app. What about all the others that have lock screen widgets (like taking a quick pic with the camera)? Perhaps they need to update their code for ICS, hmm.. Anyway, my question was about the two screens vs. one. On pre-ICS the lock screen appears before the PIN screen. On post-ICS there is no separate lock screen. Is this configurable?

Comment: Al: thanks for moving the image to imgur!  I only just today learned that that was possible.